# "subst" where indices to be equated also use subst

Tags: equality, agda, subst

I'm stuck on the following. I have the derivation of a pi calculus transition that takes place in some context Γ, plus a proof that Γ ≡ Γ′. I would like to coerce the derivation into a transition in Γ′, using `subst`. The details of the setting are mostly unimportant, as usual.

```
module Temp where
   open import Data.Nat as Nat using (_+_) renaming (ℕ to Cxt)
   open import Function
   open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

   data _⟿ (Γ : Cxt) : Set where
      bound : Γ ⟿
      nonBound : Γ ⟿

   target : ∀ {Γ} → Γ ⟿ → Cxt
   target {Γ} bound = Γ + 1
   target {Γ} nonBound = Γ

   data Proc (Γ : Cxt) : Set where
   data _—[_]→_ {Γ} : Proc Γ → (a : Γ ⟿) → Proc (target a) → Set where

   -- Use a proof that Γ ≡ Γ′ to coerce a transition in Γ to one in Γ'.
   coerce : ∀ {Γ Γ′} {P : Proc Γ} {a R} → P —[ a ]→ R → (q : Γ ≡ Γ′) →
               subst Proc q P —[ subst _⟿ q a ]→ subst (Proc ∘ target) {!!} R
   coerce E refl = {!!}
```

It's easy enough to coerce both the source P of the transition, and the action a which appears as a label on the transition. The problem is the target R of the transition, whose type depends on a. In the coerced transition, I use `subst` to coerce a from Γ ⟿ to Γ' ⟿. Naively, I would like to then also use `subst` to change the type of R from `Proc (target a)` to `Proc (target (subst _⟿ q a)` by showing that the Proc indices are equal. However, by its very nature `subst _⟿ q a` has a distinct type from a, so I'm unsure how to do this. Maybe I need to use the proof of Γ ≡ Γ′ again or somehow "undo" the inner `subst` to unify the types.

Is what I'm trying to do reasonable? If so, how do I coerce R given the heterogeneity?

Comment: Does [this](https://gist.github.com/vituscze/5c2ebb5aeb1a81358c84) work for you?

Comment: Yep, it does. Thanks. (I notice `subst'` doesn't need to take P as a parameter.)

Comment: Hmm, it seems it was a lot more trivial than I realised (as is often the case). Feel free to bump this to an answer. How generic can one get with `subst'`? Obviously you could parameterise over Proc. Or is there already something in the standard library?

Comment: I did try that with heterogeneous equality. But it seems that both `subst`s have problem with changing the type of `a` from `Γ ⟿` to `Γ′ ⟿`. There might be something in the library, but nothing I'm aware of. I'll write an answer later.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/rolyp/54542b481592516153f5) is a slightly more generic version of `subst'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you want to compare two things of different types (that can become equal given suitable reduction), you would want to use heterogeneous equality.

The proof that `subst` doesn't actually change the value cannot be done with usual (propositional) equality, because `a` and `subst P q a` have different types. However, once you know that `q = refl`, you can reduce those expressions enough so that their types now match. This can be expressed using heterogeneous equality:

```
data _≅_ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} (x : A) : {B : Set ℓ} → B → Set ℓ where
   refl : x ≅ x
```

This allows you to even express the fact that `a ≅ subst P q a`. When you then pattern match on `q`, the goal reduces to simple `a ≅ a`, which can then be proven by reflexivity:

```
≡-subst-removable : ∀ {a p} {A : Set a}
                    (P : A → Set p) {x y} (eq : x ≡ y) z →
                    P.subst P eq z ≅ z
≡-subst-removable P refl z = refl
```

---

So, the first instinct is to change the last `subst` to heterogeneous `subst` (from `Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality`) and use the proof `≡-subst-removable`. This almost works; the problem is that this `subst` cannot capture the change from `a : Γ ⟿` to `Γ′ ⟿`.

As far as I know, the standard library doesn't provide any alternate `subst`s that capture this interaction. The simple solution is to write the combinator ourselves:

```
subst′ : ∀ {Γ Γ′} {a} (q : Γ ≡ Γ′) (R : Proc (target a)) →
         Proc (target (subst _⟿ q a))
subst′ refl R = R
```

As you noted in the comments, this can be further generalized. However, unless you expect to do a lot of proofs of this kind, this generalization is not very useful since the problem is fairly rare and for the simpler cases, heterogeneous equality usually does the work.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the detailed answer. I did spot ≡-subst-removable in the library, so I'll look at using that first in the future.